# Is “whose” a true relative pronoun? (and request for the full list of relative pronouns)

Tags: syntactic-analysis, terminology, relative-pronouns, possessive-pronouns

The internet is indeed a tangled web, and since anyone can write
anything, there is a lot of conflicting information about what is
and isn’t a relative pronoun. We all agree that *who, whom, that*,
and *which* are relative pronouns. Some explanations list **only**
these four, while others also include *what, where, when*, and
*whose*. Oh, and *whoever/whomever* (and perhaps more?).

A pronoun is a word that substitutes for or refers to a noun that
is already understood based on the context in a discourse.

My confusion with *whose* is due to my understanding of possessive
adjectives (like *my, your, his, her,* and so forth) and possessive
pronouns (like *mine, yours, theirs*, and so forth).

Since possessive adjectives are not considered pronouns (right?),
then I feel as though *whose* shouldn’t be considered a true relative
pronoun. Maybe I’m overthinking it, though.

#### Example

- They’re the ones whose car we borrowed. 
  (They’re the ones.
  We borrowed their car.)

In this sentence, *whose* refers to *their* (a possessive adjective),
but I suppose it can also be said to refer to *they* or *them*, so
it can still function as a relative pronoun?

In the end, what is the complete list of relative pronouns, and
should *whose* be on it?

Comment: As usual, this is a question about terminology, and you must understand that linguistic terminology is not governed by the ISO. Partly because everybody learns their own language, which varies from everybody else's; and partly because every linguist uses their own terminology. Mine is on record, and you can find others. There are arguments that _that_ is not strictly a relative pronoun, and that _where, when, why, how, whence, whither,_ and _whether_ are relative sometimes, but not pronouns. Etc. You don't need a list; you need an explanation.

Comment: What makes something a true relative pronoun? What makes something a false relative pronoun?

Comment: You need to take a peek in a quality modern grammar textbook. Consider this example _I know the people [whose house she's renting]_.  We can represent the clause as "she's renting 'whose' house", where "whose" is understood as "people", a noun. We understand that she's renting some people's house and that I know those people. So why shouldn't "whose" be called a relative pronoun in that example?

Answer (score 1):

OK, there is no such thing as a "true" relative pronoun. Categories like this are not set by god or law, nor discovered by science. They're descriptions, and they don't describe everything.

The phrase *relative pronoun* refers to pronouns that occur with relative clauses. Not just any pronoun, but special pronouns that are, um ... relative to relative clauses. And, in English, certainly there are some. But they're busy words, and don't all relate only to relative clauses. So, what's a relative clause? No relative clauses, no relative pronouns, after all.

A relative clause is a clause -- that is, a simple sentence, with a subject and a verb, and maybe lots of other stuff -- that modifies a noun phrase. That makes it an "adjective phrase" in some grammars, but I don't like that term. It's not the only kind of clause that modifies noun phrases, but it is the most common, and therefore it's got the most confusing grammar.

Relative clauses come after the head noun of the clause they modify; this noun is called the relative clause's ***Antecedent*** (from Latin meaning 'coming before'). Relative clauses are distinguished from other types by having some coreference to the antecedent noun phrase. The relative pronoun is what substitutes for that reference; but sometimes the antecedent isn't a person or a thing, so it isn't a pronoun.

- *the **man** [**who** Bill pointed out to me]*
- *the **drink** [**which** I bought at the bar]*
- *the **time** [**when** the clock stopped]*
- *the **room** [**where** she shot him]*

In all of these, *that* can be used instead of the *wh*-words. And in all but the last one, the relative word (pronoun or not) can be deleted:

- *the **man** [Bill pointed out to me]*
- *the **drink** [I bought at the bar]*
- *the **time** [the clock stopped]*

but not

- **the **room** [she shot him]*

And then there's *how* and *why*. Both are severely restricted in relatives: *why* can only modify the antecedent *reason*, and *how* can't appear at all as a relative word, though it can be deleted after the word *way, manner,* and a few others. *That* may be used instead, in both cases.

- *the **reason** [**why** he did it]* (but not *purpose, intent,* or any other noun)
- *the **reason** [that he did it]*
- *the **reason** [he did it]*
- *the **way** [that he did it]*
- *the **way** [he did it]* (but not **the way how he did it*)

If you want to call *that* a relative pronoun, go right ahead; it can apply to anything, just about, certainly to nouns. It's really the remains of a complementizer that used to occur in tensed clauses (and still does with certain verbs -- *He thinks **that** shaving is silly*), but got stuck with some of the jobs in relative clauses, which have a lot of complexities. Whether it's part of the true, the blushful list of relative pronouns is not for me to say.

Comment: Relative pronouns are so called because they occur in relative clauses, and relative clauses are so called because they are related by their form to an antecedent. In other words they contain within their structure an anaphoric element whose interpretation is determined by the antecedent. Incidentally, relative clauses modify nominals, not full NPs.

Answer (score 0):

> Is "whose" a true relative pronoun?

Yes, it is. "Whose" reflects what is left of the old grammatical cases:

Nominative: he who

Accusative him whom

Genitive his whose

Dative [to/for] him whom

*Most of the pupils lost their books in the flood but James', whose had been on top of the cupboard, were safe.*

Comment: Yes, but it's relative because it occurs in relative clauses where it has a nominal for an antecedent.